# Plot two figures side by side in knitr without changing mfrow?

Tags: knitr

I would like to plot 2 figures side-by-side using knitr. I know I could use par(mfrow=c(1,2)), but I've done a lot of work making the figures just right as they are. 
I've seen this ([Two column layout with text and knitr chunk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83361/two-column-layout-with-text-and-knitr-chunk)), and it's not working for me.

Ideally, I'd like to do something like this (which fails):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
   \begin{columns}
      \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
          <<echo=FALSE,eval=TRUE,out.width='4cm',out.height='4cm'>>=
             plot(1:10)
          @
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
          <<echo=FALSE,eval=TRUE,out.width='4cm',out.height='4cm'>>=
             plot(1:10)
          @
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Using Sweave, I could do the following:

```
<<plot1, echo=FALSE,eval=TRUE>>=
    plot(1:10)
@

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{minipage}[h]{0.5\linewidth}
    \begin{center}

        <<label=figplotFlowSingle,echo=FALSE>>=
            <<plot1>>
        @
    \subcaption{Default plot1}
    \label{fig:plot1}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[h]{0.5\linewidth}
    \begin{center}

        <<plot2, echo=FALSE,eval=TRUE>>=
             plot(1:10)
        @

        <<label=plot22,echo=FALSE>>=
            <<plot2>>
         @
    \subcaption{Default plot2}
    \label{fig:plot2}
    \end{center}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{}
  \label{fig:plot1and2}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If all you want is two figures side by side, you can put the code in one chunk and set `fig.show='hold'` with an appropriate width, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}  

<<test, out.width='4cm', out.height='4cm', fig.show='hold'>>=
plot(1:10)
plot(rnorm(100))
@

\end{document}
```

If you want to center the figures, just add an option `fig.align='center'`. If you want to add captions, you can use `fig.cap`. See the documentation for all possible options [here](http://yihui.name/knitr/options).

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick answer and awesome package!

Comment: Does this also work for a table and a plot?